# Malware Prevention when using an IMAP library

Tags: .net, email, imap, malware

I have a .NET console application on my server that runs on a schedule and downloads emails and their attachments for viewing/processing through a document-management-type web application. The emails are stored in a SQL database and the attachments saved to the file system. These emails could theoretically contain malicious attachments, which when downloaded could harm my system. Correct?

How do I prevent this? Is there some type of library I can use to scan the attachment before downloading it? Or another method of accomplishing this task that would mitigate this risk?

Comment: Downloading something can't hurt your system, it's just data. Until you open it or run it, it's just a collection of bytes.

Comment: @Max OK, so as long as the server doesn't execute or open the file, I don't have to worry about whether it is malware or not?

Comment: Generally, yes.  You're just moving a collection of bytes from one place to another.  The issues with malware come when you display, open, run, etc. it.  That is, attempt to interpret the bytes somehow.